# Is there a way to tell who pushed a change in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

If I see a commit authored/committed by `John Doe <jdoe@gmail.com>`, is there any way to tell which GitHub user pushed this commit to my GitHub:Enterprise repository (assuming there are a number of users that have write access)?

Comment: To do that, you would have to store push information in the git datatree, which would get overwhelming in a DVCS. You could check the creation time of one of the blobs of that commit and correlate it with the ssh/git/something login logs.

Comment: So you're saying I'd be SOL if I wanted this information on an existing repository?

Comment: Ask github support, maybe they have something specific to their software.

Comment: Done.  :-)  Will post back if I get anything generally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes a bit of effort, but as you might know, there is a [Github REST Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/). Depending on your setup (single user vs Enterprise) you might find the right resource to pull user information for your repo. From there, you could interpolate which github user did the commit.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not looking for the user that did the commit (they may well not exist on github), I'm looking for the user that pushed the commit (they must have existed on github).

Comment: Supposing the GH Enterprise API has the same functionality as the github.com API, there's the [Events Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/), look at the [Push Event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), the response contains **pusher/name/email**.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Or rather, it would be nice if it were in the UI, but the fact that I can get to it (and script against it) definitely covers my needs.

Comment: As a side note: [OctoKit](https://github.com/octokit) provides SDKs for GH Api - might come in handy if you want to do advanced stuff ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again @codeclash. I've just used this again to find out who pushed a naughty commit directly to master with a misconfigured author name :-)

Answer (score 0):

This capability does exist in the GitHub Enterprise UI (referencing version 11.10.343) ... if you're an admin:

1. As an Admin-level user, navigate to the repository in question
2. Click the rocket icon (Admin tools) in the upper-right of the screen
3. In the left-hand nav, click "Push Log"

That screen gives you a "Copy push log" button, so if you aren't an admin, you may be able to request that from your admin.